# Heroku CLI does not recognize kafka as a command

Tags: heroku, apache-kafka

When using the Heroku CLI, I get the following error message:

> kafka is not a heroku command

I get this when I run `heroku help kafka` or `heroku kafka:topics`

I have installed the Heroku toolbelt and am able to login. If I run `heroku apps`, I am able to see a list of my apps.
Has anyone else encountered this error with kafka on the command line?

Answer (score 10):

Sorry. I just realised that you need to install the

> heroku-kafka cli plugin

Use this command: `heroku plugins:install heroku-kafka`